# Redesigning the node comment while using the nodecomment module

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-comments

I am using nodecomment module in drupal 6.2. I need to change the design, look and feel of the comments attached to each node. Since i am using the nodecomment module so , i added few extra fields to the comments which needs to be repositioned and redesigned.

Being a novice in drupal, I have absolutely no idea how do i proceed. Please help

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go fairly far with CSS and the "Manage Fields" and "Display Fields" settings of your content type.  For more in-depth changes, you can override the node-comment.tpl.php for the comment nodes and view templates for different listings of contents.